# How do I reset a DependencyProperty back to it's default value in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm implementing a user-adjustable `Effect` using sliders and I have a reset button beside the slider. The idea is to allow the user to reset back to the default value of the `Effect`'s property as specified in metadata.

I think it might be trivial to do that in XAML.

Comment: Since Xaml is not procedural this question doesn't make a great deal of sense.  Try eloborating on why you would want to do this?

Comment: and at what time, based on some condition, trigger etc?

Answer (score 4):

Dependency properties don't really have default values.  If a dependency property doesn't have a local value, it will obtain its value either through value inheritance or through coercion, depending on how the property has been implemented.

You can't really get rid of the property's local value in XAML - that would require you to call `ClearValue` on the property, and there's no way to find the object and call a method on it declaratively.  But as long as the property's getting its value through value inheritance (instead of value coercion) - you can accomplish fundamentally the same thing by binding the property to the property it's inheriting from on the appropriate ancestor

For instance, here's a style you'd use to create a `ListBox` that sets the foreground color of all items that *aren't* selected:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter 
               Property="Foreground" 
               Value="{Binding 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox},
                  Path=Foreground}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This basically explicitly implements value inheritance through binding.  It does mean that the `ListBoxItem.Foreground` property now *has* a local value, and that whenever you change the `Foreground` property on the `ListBox` it's binding that updates the `ListBoxItem.Foreground` and not the dependency-property system.  This might actually matter if you have hundreds of thousands of items in your `ListBox`.  But in most real-world cases, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: The problem is that that only works for WPF and SL5.  SL4 does not have RelativeSource=FindAncestor

Comment: You discouraged the use of ClearValue. So i did exactly that.

Comment: "*Dependency properties don't really have default values*", [they have one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertymetadata.defaultvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_PropertyMetadata_DefaultValue) which is at [low priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) when the dependency property must be evaluated. In contrary, the local value has the highest priority. When clearing this local value, the value with the next highest priority is taken, and this may not be the default value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid logic cycles, **WPF** strongly resists attempts to set a `DependencyProperty` value to its current value. This is a problem during initialization, where you'd like to have dependent logic triggered to set everything up *for the first time* based on the `DefaultValue` recorded in the metadata, for each of the various dependent properties. WPF won't do it because, as a special case, all those properties already obtain their default values without ever having executed any such logic.

As far as I can tell, no combination of `InvalidateProperty`, `CoerceValue`, or `ClearValue` will convince WPF to do the work. A trivial fix would be to somehow conjure a hopefully harmless non-default value to change it to, and then after that, reset the value via `ClearValue`. This seems hacky, though, since it may not be practical to determine a "harmless" value. Perhaps worse, this approach will unnecessarily ripple the dependency graph twice, instead of just once.

As a perhaps more elegant solution, you can call the following extension method in the constructor of each relevant object to manually invoke the `PropertyChanged` logic for each `DependencyProperty` that needs to have its changes propagated. This helper will trigger follow-on changes according the default value stored in the respective metadata.

```
public static void ResetValue(this DependencyObject _this, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    var md = dp.GetMetadata(_this.GetType());
    if (_this.GetValue(dp).Equals(md.DefaultValue))
    {
        var args = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(dp, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, md.DefaultValue);
        md.PropertyChangedCallback(_this, args);
    }
    else
        _this.ClearValue(dp);
}
```

As shown, the function includes a check to see if `ClearValue` would in fact be effective, so beyond initialization scenarios, you can also use this function as a replacement for `ClearValue` in general. For clarity of demonstration, this method does not verify that the host object in fact exposes any property-change logic, but this would be a simple change. In C# 7, for example:

```
        // ...
        md.PropertyChangedCallback?.Invoke(_this, args);
```

Example usage in your class:

```
class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDp = /* ... */

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.ResetValue(MyDp);
        /* ... */
    }
};
```