# How to get default value for DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have issue to set all controls values by button click to default. 
Problem that this is not working when style is set.

For example i have code:

```
               var metadata = dependencyProperty.DefaultMetadata;

                if (value == null)
                {
                    return metadata.DefaultValue == value;
                }
                else
                {
                    return value.Equals(metadata.DefaultValue);
                }
```

But this is not actually default properties! Because in styles can be other values set! 
How to get really "default" proprties for control!? So WPF will also return value from style if such is set?

P.s. ClearValue(propertyToClear); cannot be used because in some cases i need to check values.

Comment: "in some cases i need to check values." what do you mean by that? The property will still have a value in that case, which is the default value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There might be different metadata for different dependency object types. Hence you would have to get the property metadata for a specific type by one of the [GetMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522464) overloads.

```
var metadata = dependencyProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(SomeDependencyObject));
var defaultValue = metadata.DefaultValue;
```

Comment: Sure. This is correct. But this value will be wrong if style set. Because style can override this metadata value.

Comment: Right. What about getting the actual value by [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue), then do [ClearValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.clearvalue), GetValue again for the "default" value, then reset the actual value by [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue). Complicated, but i can't currently see another way.

Comment: There is also [DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource), but i'm afraid that it won't help much here.

Comment: Yes. Now i am using this Get value source because i dont see other way to get real default value. About suggested "clear value" i cannot do this because i need to clear value only if i need to set default value as new... This is strange behaviour but i need to do this)

Comment: Perhaps you extend you question and try to explain why exactly you can't simply clear all values. Maybe somebody finds a way around this problem.

Comment: Regarding your "Complicated, but I can't currently see another way...", check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731434/147511 for my alternative spin on this.